# Multiple ip-camera streams on the same activity in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, ip-camera

I'm trying to display multiple streams from ip-cameras on the same activity. I found a class that extends surfaceview and applied it, but actually this works for only one instance of this class; the other instances doesn't work. How can I display multiple surface views on the same activity in android. If not possible, so how can I display multiple streams at the same time; I see that some programs do this, but I don't know how.